# Getting input hidden value from string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following code (live: http://jsfiddle.net/xyZY8/1/):

```
var str = '<div>hello</div><ul><li>Some text...</li>' + 
          '<li>second item</li></ul>' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="some_int" value="15" />';

var myVal = $(str).find("input[name=some_int]").val();

alert(myVal);
```

I want to get input hidden value. But this code does not work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create new HTML using `$('<html string here>')`, a new jQuery object will be created, containing all elements:

```
div     When you use `.find()`, the childs of the first element, <div> in this
ul        case, are checked.
    li
    li
input
```

Use `filter()` if you want to select one of these childs.

```
var myVal = $(str).filter("input[name=some_int]").val();
```

You can also wrap the HTML in a container, so that `find()` can be used:

```
var myVal = $("<div>").append(str).find("input[name=some_int]").val();
```